# What am I doing wrong to validate a full name input in a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, form-fields

I tried using the code below for a **Full Name validation** in a single input field **with a space between the texts**(a space between the first and second name). But for some reasons I couldn't make it work! Will you guys please kindly have a look at it?

This is the code:

```js
<script>
  lp.jQuery(function($) {
  
    var ruleID = 'fullNameValid';
    var field = 'full_name';
    var message = 'Please enter a valid full name';
  
    var rules = module.lp.form.data.validationRules[field];
  
    $.validator.addMethod(ruleID, function(value, field) {
      var valid = /^[a-zA-Z ]$/.test(value);
      return valid || (!rules.required && !value);
    }, message);
  
    rules[ruleID] = true;
  
  });
</script>
```

I have also tried using these options:

```js
1.... var valid = /^[a-zA-Z ]$/.test(value);
2.... var valid = /^[a-zA-Z/s]$/.test(value);
3.... var valid = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(value);
4.... var valid = /^[a-zA-Z/s]+$/.test(value);
5.... var valid = /^([a-zA-Z ])$/.test(value));
6.... var valid = /^([a-zA-Z/s])$/.test(value));
7.... var valid = /^([a-zA-Z ]+)$/.test(value));
8.... var valid = /^([a-zA-Z/s]+)$/.test(value));
```

But the validation doesn't work! What am I doing wrong?

And this is my page: http://unbouncepages.com/pradaxa-one/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: You seem to believe rather a lot of these: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var valid = /^[a-z]+ [a-z]+$/i

Maybe this regex can help you.
And you should trim the value at first.

Comment: This would match "Jon _ _ _ Doe" as well. It only should have "one space". Underscore mentioned as spaces

Comment: Now it just matches one space, but as addition it matches tabs, enter, line breaks. Here the you find the [documentation of \s](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp)

Comment: Hey @wuxiandiejia  how will the code be for names with ' or - ? for example: Jeff-Blue Walker or Ha'aina James.  Also for multiple spaces between names or for may be for first middle and last name the first code you wrote will work fine I guess,right? I mean this: var valid = /[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+/i

Comment: @Mahabul Islam try `/^[A-Z][a-z]+('[a-z]+|([- ][A-Z][a-z]+))? [A-Z][a-z]+$/`

Comment: Thanks! This works pretty well actually. Great job. Can this also be extended for names having . or () ?? for example: Dr.Jim Jacobs or Mahabul Islam (Nayon) . Also the spaces extended to 4! so, it works with people entering their first name+middle name+sur name and last name altogether. @wuxiandiejia   Thanks in advance again.

Comment: @Mahabul Islam Is the longest name like Dr.Jim Jacobs Mahabul Islam (Nayon)?

Comment: @Mahabul Islam You can learn `RegExp` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: @wuxiandiejia yeah, something like that! I need 7 spaces implementation and also special character insertion too! i.e special characters like ' . - ()

Comment: I would start learning it too. Thanks for your help man. Really appreciate it. Could you just provide me script for the above condition for now? I need to implement it. I will let you know about my learning updates and share my experiences while learning.

Comment: @Mahabul Islam  Maybe `/^([A-Z][a-z]\.)?[A-Z][a-z]+('[a-z]+)?([- ][A-Z][a-z]+){0,2} [A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)?$/` works.

Comment: @wuxiandiejia Thanks again! But unfortunately doesn't work!

Comment: @wuxiandiejia  I guess it becomes more complex with giving more spaces to it! The previous one you gave works fine with 2 spaces and special characters like ' and -

I was thinking how to extend it and limit to 4 spaces and have only 2 more characters . and () added to it
So it would validate names like: david john booth (williams) or Dr. Fahima Zerin Khan and also Jeff-Blue Walker or Ha'aina James
I mean to extend this one: /^[A-Z][a-z]+('[a-z]+|([- ][A-Z][a-z]+))? [A-Z][a-z]+$/

Comment: @Mahabul Islam Is it possible the name has both  . and ()?Dr.Ha'aina and Dr.Jeff-Blue are valid?

Comment: @wuxiandiejia yes! a name can also have both characters at the same time.

Comment: @wuxiandiejia  Just need to have 4 spaces and able to put special characters . - ' () on the names. [probably one at a time or 2 on the same name like the example you showed above]

Comment: @MahabulIslam It may has 2 to 4 spaces?The count of special characters is 0 to 3?Or 0 to 2？

Comment: @wuxiandiejia yes, exactly! 2 to 4 spaces and count of special characters is 0 to 2. But must validate all these 4 characters - ' . ()

Comment: @wuxiandiejia  any luck? Thanks

Comment: @MahabulIslam sorry,I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(/^([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+)$/.test("John     Doe"));
console.log(/^([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+)$/.test("John Doe"));
console.log(/^([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+)$/.test("Jóhn Doe"));
console.log(/^([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+)$/.test("John Dö"));
```

It **ONLY** matches the alphabet in lower and uppercase. It does not validate Names with special characters as: "Jóhn Doe", "John Düstre"...